# Content provider not working in one plus devices

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, oneplusone, oneplustwo

I have two applications, one contains content provider and other app receives data using content resolver. If i add any data form provider that should be displayed from receiver in second app, this is the expected functionality.**But after adding data once I remove first app from stack then second app displays null cursor**,If I keep first app in stack, then second app displays correct value .(**This issue only comes in one plus devices**)

code snippet where cursor value coming null is,

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it will help you

```
 private String uriToFilename(Uri uri) {
    String path = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        path = getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, uri);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        path = getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, uri);
    } else {
        path = getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, uri);
    }

    return path;
}
```

**BelowAPI11**

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index
            = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

**API11to18**

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**API19**

```
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Log.e("uri", uri.getPath());
        String filePath = "";
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            Log.e("wholeID", wholeID);
// Split at colon, use second item in the array
            String[] splits = wholeID.split(":");
            if (splits.length == 2) {
                String id = splits[1];

                String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
// where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            filePath = uri.getPath();
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable Don’t optimize inside Settings to resolve one plus issue.

Settings –> Battery –> Battery Optimization –> Your App –> Don’t optimize
[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc5nD.png)

Comment: This is not the way. every user can' give a permission. or if you prompt user to remove app from battery optimization list then app will be rejected from play store.